# Using javascript to add Person lookup field

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, custom-list

I'm working on a SharePoint Add In and some list provisioning code. I want to add a Person column to my list. I searched the docs and came up short.

```
list.get_fields().addFieldAsXml('<Field DisplayName="Responsible" Type="Lookup" List="?" Required="TRUE" Name="User" />', true, SP.AddFieldOptions.defaultValue);
```

The list would be kept in the host web, not the app web.

Answer (score 0):

To add lookup column we have to specify list/library URL. like, `List="lists/Country"` or `List="Share Documents"`.
Please make sure for provisioning lookup column you have to set below parameter  value.

```
<Field 
    ID="{0dd154e3-a30e-44ca-a158-c8808afd2327}" 
    Name="Responsible" 
    StaticName="Responsible"        
    DisplayName="Responsible" 
    Type="Lookup" 
    List="{Provide list Url}" 
    ShowField="{lookup field name}"
    Required="FALSE" 
    Group="Custom column" />
```